# Take the result of call for a list of ids

Tags: python

Using a simple example it runs fine

```
from stackapi import StackAPI
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow', key="xxxxxxx")
SITE.max_pages=10000000
SITE.page_size=100
post = SITE.fetch('/users/{ids}/reputation-history', ids=[11786778])
```

However if I try to run it into a for loop for a list of users and keep the results of every iteration into a variables which will have all results I fail:

Any idea how can I fix it?

```
lst = ['11786778','12370060']
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow', key="xxxx")
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    SITE.max_pages=10000000
    SITE.page_size=100
    post = SITE.fetch('/users/{ids}/reputation-history', ids=lst[i])
```

Comment: put all in your loop : `range(len(df))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because list indices start from 0, not 1. `range(1, len(df))` means `i` starts from 1, so in `SITE.fetch` you are using only `ids=lst[1]`

```
for i in range(len(df))
```

To keep all results of `fetch` use list of dict

```
results = []
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    SITE.max_pages=10000000
    SITE.page_size=100
    post = SITE.fetch('/users/{ids}/reputation-history', ids=lst[i])
    results.append(post)
```

Comment: and why post keeps only the last item of lst? I tried this post2 = post + post2 for every iteration to keep all data but it is not possible

Comment: @Nathalie `fetch` return `dict`, you can't use `+=` on it. See updated answer.

Comment: thank you it is right. Any idea how could I make the results as dataframe. This doesn't provide the right results: `import pandas as pd; pd.DataFrame(results)`

Comment: @Nathalie I'm on the phone, I'll try to check later.

Comment: @Thank you please run this `post = SITE.fetch('/users/{ids}/reputation-history', ids=[lst[i]])` to take the right option of results

Comment: @Nathalie What are the results you are getting and what do you expect to get instead?